# Maven dependency:tree is not showing all transitive dependencies

Tags: maven

I have trouble understanding the behaviour of the **depencendy:tree** output. When running the plugin on a higher module, I am missing vital information from modules it depends on. But when I run the plugin on the lower module I can see the depencendies. Here is an example to show the problem (names changed):

```
mvn -pl foo:bar-application dependency:tree -Dincludes=foo:*
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bar-application 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ bar-application ---
[INFO] foo:bar-application:ear:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- foo:bar-business:ejb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- foo:common-util:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
...
[INFO] +- foo:bar-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] \- foo:common-logging:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The tree shows a depencendy to **bar-web**, but only one further depencendy from **bar-web** to other projects (**common-logging**).

But **bar-web** has far more dependencies:

```
mvn -pl foo:bar-web dependency:tree -Dincludes=foo:*
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bar-web 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ bar-web ---
[INFO] foo:bar-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- foo:common-logging:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- foo:culprit-business-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
...
[INFO] +- foo:common-rest:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- foo:config-business-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] \- foo:bar-business:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO]    \- foo:some-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why are the other dependencies not shown when inspecting **bar-application**? It took me a while of searching to find the **culprit**.
Im a using

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.5
```

Comment: First you should use an up-to-date version of maven-dependency-plugin and not such ancient version..best is to call: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree` ...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did try version 2.10 but the output is exactly the same.

Comment: I am also seeing same behavior. `mvn dependency:tree` is listing all the transitive dependencies except for one particular dependency X whose transitive dependencies it does not list. When I run `mvn dependency:tree` on `pom.xml` of X it lists all its dependencies very similar to what this question has.

Answer (score 7):

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

shows you the effective dependencies, as in where your actual dependencies come from.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

will show you all transitive dependencies including the reasonwhy they are excluded

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Sadly I no longer have the specific sources available to see if that would help in my original situation. But I am quite certain that in my example from 2015 the dependency that I was looking for (`foo:culprit-business-client:jar`) was not duplicated anywhere in the dependency tree of `foo:bar-application:ear`.

Comment: It is important to notice that -Dverbose flag is not supported since maven-dependency-plugin 3.0. Alternatively, you can use 'mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree -Dverbose=true'.

Comment: @LucianoBrum using 2.1 made no difference. The 4th party dependencies already pulled into the project by some other dependency wont be listed in the tree.

Comment: I have the same problem (in the war I see a jar that doesn't appear at all in the tree) and the `verbose` flag doesn't help, furthermore current documentation says it is unreliable, see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#verbose

Answer (score 2):

A WAR includes its dependencies inside the archive, that's why Maven does not propagate them transitively to other artifacts depending on the WAR artifact.

Comment: But when running maven goals like **compile** the dependencies are recognized and included in the build. Is there any way to enforce this behaviour when listing dependencies? My problem here was to find the unwanted dependency that caused unwanted projects to show up in my build.

Comment: Further: If you are correct, why is **common-logging** shown as a dependency of **bar-web** but none of its other dependencies?

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` will exclude duplicate dependencies by default. The reason is the way the Java classpath works; if (say) a.jar is already being included in the classpath, having it declared again "later" in the classpath is quite pointless. If you run the command with `-Dverbose=true`, the plugin will include omitted artifacts.