# Maven dependency shows in dependency tree but no jar is imported

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit5

The project I am working at has many levels and a parent pom, so, hard to assess the ultimate result of dependencies imported.

However, looking into the dependency:tree and the effective pom, I can see i am correctly importing JUnit-jupiter 5.5.2, but i cannot see the jar on the list of maven dependencies on my project, I actually see JUnit-jupiter 5.2.0 .

Already tried mvc clean install -U

Any ideas?

jars and dependecy:tree
[image: jars and dependecy:tree]

effective-pom[image: effective-pom]

Comment: Is IntelliJ showing any errors when it imports the Maven configuration?

Comment: Does code have any complication error related to Junit classes?

Comment: The reason for JUnit-jupiter 5.2.0 is still in your project could be due to , it comes as a transitive dependency of some other dependency. What you can do is look for parent dependency of JUnit-jupiter 5.2.0 and exclude transitive dependencies from it.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe. No. It doesn't show any errors, it is as if it was all clean and good.

Comment: @SandunkaMihiran But if it was coming from a transitive dependency it would show in the dependency:tree or the effective-pom. However there is no reference to v 5.2.0 on those.

Comment: @Laguh Sometimes dependency:tree won't show all transitive dependencies.Worth a try from graphical tree .Explained @ -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529795/maven-dependencytree-is-not-showing-all-transitive-dependencies?rq=1

Comment: It indeed was not showing in the dependency:tree. It was coming from my parent pom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for JUnit-jupiter 5.2.0 is still in your project could be due to , it comes as a transitive dependency of some other dependency. What you can do is look for parent dependency of JUnit-jupiter 5.2.0 and exclude transitive dependencies from it.

[image: Use graphical dependency tree of your project and expand all transitive dependencies and search jupiter lib]

Use graphical dependency tree of your project and expand all transitive dependencies and search jupiter library. 
If there is JUnit-jupiter 5.2.0 as a transitive dependency you can exclude it as below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.some.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-library</artifactId>
        <version>${parent.library.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It was coming from the parent pon . So i declared the dependency with exclusions on the <dependencymanagement> .

Answer (score 0):

Managed to import the correct jar by excluding the transitive dependency in dependency management in pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```